# Money making in Runescape

Tags: runescape

I have 99 magic, 99 fletching, 91 firemaking and 83 woodcutting, and no money.

How can I make money using the skills I listed above?

Comment: Account trading (this includes giving) is against the rules of Runescape, and can get you permanently banned.

Comment: originally it was mine but i stopped playing them my brother played on it and now he has to go to the army so he gave it to me, its not account trading we share it and we had it for years and a few mods on forums know that we share it and we are not banned yet, we had it for 6 years

Comment: are you going to go f2p or member?

Comment: member sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: take a look that: http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Money_making_guide

Comment: Any kind of sharing/trading/more than one person on an account is against the rules. It's also never enforced (except powertraining) so it's pointless to mention it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make money with 99 fletching?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43619/how-can-i-make-money-with-99-fletching)

Comment: use a bot! works the best!

Comment: Real money or virtual coins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Killing mature grotworms near Port Sarim will harvest about 1.7 Billion gp if you do it for 1 month. You make about 3m an hour! It commonly drops rune items and ores/seeds/armour/potions and the legendary royal dragonhide. It is the absolutly best way to make cash quick.

[image]

Comment: @Gerwin If you disagree with the math, you can post your own answer.  Don't modify someone else's.

Comment: @Frank who even games 17hours a day lol, that's WAY too unrealistic, let's be honest here.

Comment: @Gerwin Then write your own answer to that effect. Disagree with the math or not, but that's not what suggested edits are for.

Answer (score 7):

This is a high alchemy calculator: http://www.scape-xp.com/runescape-high-alchemy.html
You can find the most profitable items to alch on here every day.

Dicing and flowering and such are incredibly unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

You can always cut down trees and sell them in the Grand Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

With just those skills you can do nothing other than woodcutting. If you want to give us more info then we can help you more. =)

Comment: those are the only high stats i have, but my combat skills are all 71-72 and everything else is around 50-60 ish

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of money making methods in the game. The most obvious example with the information given is woodcutting. Given these stats, I'm going to assume that you have reasonable stats in everything else, for the sake of simplicity.

If you have completed Throne of Miscelania (and, optionally, but desirably, Royal Trouble), then you can use Kingdom Managing to make money. The profits on each thing vary depending on current market prices, so check [this calculator](http://runescape.wiki/w/Calculator:Other/Miscellania) can be helpful to optimize profits.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to earn money in Rune Scape which everyone knows, like cutting yews or killing Green (Wildy), Blue (East Falador) or Black (Same dungeon than blue) Dragons. But these methods will make you play and click for ever and you will only get a decent amount of money with it.

If you want to know some money making methods that will make you really rich, and with rich I mean earn over 100M per month, I will sum them for you.

I haven't played for over a year now but last time I played I earned over 150M the last month. I got a bank of Green h'ween, Santa DClaws and 45M cash.

My three methods:

- Dual arena Scamming (look on youtube for useful and powerful dual arena scams)
- Merching (also decent you should do this smart and with some friends, create a clan and make other people suffer from your profits)
- Dicing!!
  With his method I earned most of my money. I never really liked the game itself but I did like making money. I created my own clan [with website](http://securedicing.webs.com/).
  The whole dicing process is explained at the clan website which is still online. Ít is important not to scam people because even if they win they will always come back to dice again and eventually they will lose because you got 55% chance to win and they got 45% chance.
  I started with 30M which I made with merching (there are plenty of merch guides on the Internet) and with that 30M I did 500k bets max, that means a 1M pot because you put 500k in the pot from yourelf.

Comment: It should be noting that player run games of chance are explicitly against the rules, separately from scamming.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do still is to buy seeds (cabbage at 3gp, hammerstone at 5gp, Jute at 5gp, and asgarnian at 4gp) then sell them to Olivia in Draynor Village for more cash (Cabbage 7gp, Hammerstone 18gp, Jute 25gp, asgarnian at 16gp)!

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a realistic version of the accepted answer which was made by Young Guilo.

Killing mature grotworms near Port Sarim will harvest about 360 Million gp if you do it for 1 month. You make about 3m an hour! It commonly drops rune items and ores/seeds/armour/potions and the legendary royal dragonhide. It is the absolutly best way to make cash quick.

the math -

3.000.000 gp (3m) / hour, playing for an average of 4 hours a day results in 12.000.000 gp (12m) per day, if you do this for one month it'll result in 360.000.000 gp (360m) / month